# How can I start a flash video from javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash, playback

Is it possible to start playing a file inside a flash player by making use of javascript code? If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [swfObject](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/), you can make any actionscript function visible for javascript using `ExternalInterface` and declaring them into javascript. So you can trigger actionscript function with `play()` (or any other code you want) from your javascript code.

Here is an example:

Actionscript:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.addCallback( "methodName", this, method );
function method() {
   trace("called from javascript");
}
```

Javascript:

```
function callAS() {
   swf.methodName(); 
}
```

Where methodName is the identifier js uses to call the method from actionscript.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [SWFObject](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/). There a lot of examples on how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. You can reference the flash movie objects from js and control the flash component in a page. Unfortunately the way you do it is not portable across browsers. See this:

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/

Answer (score 2):

If you HAVE to do it from Javascript consider flipping ON the autoplay parameter like so:

Assuming you've grabbed the parent of the object/embed ( vidParent ):

```
if( document.all) {
  // toggle the object code (IE)
  vidParent.innerHTML = vidParent.innerHTML.replace(/0\" name=\"autoplay/gi,'1\" name=\"autoplay');
} else {
  // toggle the embed code
  vidParent.innerHTML = vidParent.innerHTML.replace(/autoplay=0/gi,'autoplay=1'); 
}
```

This will reload the flash with autoplay = 1 ( this example works with the YouTube player ).

I had to do this to do some tracking on video plays.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting method is suggested here: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/

Works for me!

The idea is to get `embed` object using

```
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName)
{
  if (window.document[movieName]) 
  {
      return window.document[movieName];
  }
  if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
  {
    if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
      return document.embeds[movieName]; 
  }
  else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
  {
    return document.getElementById(movieName);
  }
}
```

and to call its `Play()` method afterwards.

```
getFlashMovieObject('MyMovie').Play()
```

A couple of other methods are supported, see the link above.

Answer (score 1):

You can call any custom function in Flash from JavaScript, which requires you coding both Javascript and Flash.

See here for some examples: http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_15683.

Also, using [SwfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) helps a long way when dealing with Flash from JavaScript.

Comment: does this mean that I'm not able to play it if the flash part wasn't written by me? I can just add JS code to the page, but not flash.

Comment: No, you can't control compiled flash movie from javascript without using ExternalInterface.

Comment: @Geo: exactly. If you want to play Flash movies, you need to have complete control over its code and behavior. If it's a third-party movie, then you cannot control it (unless, of course, you decompile it and add some code to it, but that's something you never heard from me :P).

Comment: My plans of world domination are ruined!