# Debugging ActionScript in Browser

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to implement following:

[How can I start a flash video from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668377/how-can-i-start-a-flash-video-from-javascript)

However I am unable to call method from Javascript. The trace message I wrote within AS file is not able to see while calling file within browser.

How can I test whether my JS function is calling AS method or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FlashBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14465/) addon for Firefox lets you see Flash trace outputs in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to create a javascript function that only has an alert function inside. 
try calling it, you either get the pop-up or you don't.

---

*edit:*

Alert is a javascript command, but you can call it directly from flash using external interface call.

as:

```
var call_java:uint;
call_java = ExternalInterface.call('alert','!!!');
```

**or...** call the alert from a function
 AS:

```
var call_java:uint;
call_java = ExternalInterface.call('myFunction','!!!');
```

javascript:

```
funciton myFunction(val)
{
    alert(val);
}
```

Comment: additionally check if you have set `allowScriptAccess:"always"` or `allowScriptAccess:"sameDomain"`

Comment: I am quite ignorant about AS. What is the method to call Alert within Action Script? I called alert() and Alert and both did not work

Answer (score 0):

here is the code which I am using:

> import flash.external.*;
>
> var flashFunction:String =
>   "jsstopMainVideo";  var
>   realFunction:Function = stopMainVideo;
>   function stopMainVideo(){
>     trace("called from javascript");
>     //flvPlayer.stop(); }
>
> //stopMainVideo();
>
> var wasSuccessful:Boolean =
>   ExternalInterface.addCallback(flashFunction,
>   null, realFunction);

In JS I am doing:

> var me = null; function
>   getID( swfID ){
>        if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")
>   != -1){
>             me = window[swfID];
>        }else{
>             me = document[swfID];
>        }      } getID("signupVideoVideo");
>   
>    me.jsstopMainVideo();

I am getting JS error that function **me.jsstopMainVideo()** is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Just check this example http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html , maybe you forgot something