# Start playing swf when jquery .animate is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, jquery-ui

I have an swf inside a div that is hidden. It is stopped in frame 1 and I want it to start playing when a jquery script is done. Here is my code:

```
    function doFlash() {
    $("#first_menu").hide("clip", { direction: "vertical" }, 500, function() {
    $('#flash_container').animate({top: 0}, 1500, function(){
    getElementById('FlashID').Play()});});
    };
```

But it is not working at all, it do the animation but don't start playing the swf. Thanxs in advance.

UPDATE: The wmode:transparent issue is fixed now, but the swf is still not playing in FF and Chrome. I used swfobject as Fabrício Matté suggested me, but for some reason it is just working in IE. I think that maybe is something about the id of the oject, but i'm not sure. Here's the link to the example: http://molcajete.com.mx/natura/videos_fito/ Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you put one of these answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/668377/1331430 inside of your callback it should work.

Comment: Which answer? The swfObject should work cross-browser.

Comment: I've tried the swfObject but I'm having problems with FF and Chrome. It is working ok in IE but in Chrome and FF is not working and the wmode:transparent is gonne :-( At least is half the way! If you want to check it [link](http://molcajete.com.mx/natura/videos_fito/) Thanxs.

Answer (score 0):

This API : http://api.jquery.com/stop/ or `.is('animate')` might help to check if animation is done.

Also if you want, you can set a callback to be called when the animation is done: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate

**Sample code**

```
if( $("#fooDov").is(":animated") ){
  alert("HULK!");
}
```

**your code**

```
  function doFlash() {
    $("#first_menu").hide("clip", { direction: "vertical" }, 500, function() {
    $('#flash_container').animate({top: 0}, 1500, function(){
       if( $(this).is(":animated") )
            getElementById('FlashID').Play()});});
    };
```

Comment: Hi Tats. Thanxs for answer. The jquery animation is working, what I want to do is to tell an swf to start playing after the animation is done: here is the sample: [link](http://molcajete.com.mx/natura/videos_fito/)

Comment: Hiya @RodolfoAwenyddLunaBernal howz it, Yep so you will check that with `.is('animated')` to checdk if animation is done or use `stop` api can you jsfiddle it I might help you out, no probs. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I only needed to write the 'name' at the object.