# Start flash playback from javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

I have this Flash embedded in my page:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="180" height="76" id="SignUpTop1" align="middle">
<param name="movie" value="/Videos/SignUpTop1.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<param name="play" value="false" />
<param name="loop" value="false" />
<param name="wmode" value="window" />
<param name="scale" value="showall" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />
<param name="devicefont" value="false" />
<param name="salign" value="" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/Videos/SignUpTop1.swf" width="180" height="76">
    <param name="movie" value="/Videos/SignUpTop1.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="play" value="false" />
    <param name="loop" value="false" />
    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="menu" value="false" />
    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
    <param name="salign" value="" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<!--<![endif]-->
    <div style="height:180px">&nbsp;</div>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

I want to start playback of the flash movie 5 seconds after the page is loaded. So, I do:

```
 setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById("SignUpTop1").play();}, 5000);
```

And, getting this error in Chrome:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'play'

What is the proper way to start a Flash playback from Javascript? A code sample would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I believe this is a syntax error, not sure though.

Comment: Looks like this is already answered in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668377/how-can-i-start-a-flash-video-from-javascript

Comment: That post suggests that I need to expose play method in via ActionScript. Is that really the only way to call a Flash movie from Javascript? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

try using,

```
setTimeout(function () {var movie=eval(window.document[\'SignUpTop1\']); movie.play();}, 5000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function () {var movie=eval(document[\'SignUpTop1\']); movie.play();}, 5000);
```